# MainActivity scrolls back to top position after coming back from RestaurantDetailActivity

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am testing out this [fireStore FreindlyEats app](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/firestore) from GitHub to dev my own app but I found one issue with scrolling as mentioned below

On `MainAcitivty` 
If I scroll down and click on very bottom restaurant, `RestaurantDetailActivity` will open,
after hitting back or close button at `RestaurantDetailActivity`, the `MainActivty` scrolls back top position dispute I am scrolled to the bottom and selected bottom one restaurant

I tried to develop My own app and found the same issue `MainActivity` scrolls back to top position after coming back from `RestaurantDetailActivity`

and checked out FireStore app found the same `mRestaurantsRecycler` at `MainActivity` scrolls back to top position after coming back from `RestaurantDetailActivity`

Is there any way to workaround to solve this?

Thank you

**Update**

[Here I found the answer to my question at GitHub repo issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/383)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Firebase. Saving adapter positions is something you must do

Comment: Thanks for commenting cricket_007, can you tell how to save or remember the adapter position

Comment: Feel free to create a new post if you want help with that

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just did this tutorial myself learning Cloud Firestore. 
Basically what happens is that the `RestaurantDetailActivity` and `MainActivity` are two `Acivitys` independent from one another. Before you open (go to) the  `RestaurantDetailActivity` you have to save the position the adapter(restaurang list) is at. When you press back button and leaving the `RestaurantDetailActivity` the `MainActivity` is brought back to front and the first code running is

```
public void onStart() {...
```

If you follow the code you see that everytime `MainActivity` starts or resumes(onStart()) the adapter is reset and all restaurants are reloaded. This is for demo purpose only, to only show the functionality of the Cloud Firestore. What you must do is stop restart `MainActivity` `adapter`  every time you go to it(backpress on the `RestaurantDetailActivity` ) and reconfigure the code so that the adapter can remember the position it was on.

When you have done that this code will position the adapter(restaurant list) at what position you like:

> ```
>         mRestaurantsRecycler.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount());
> ```

Here the doc for [activity-lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

**UPDATE:**

Remember this is just a simple example stopping the adapter from reloading every time `MainActivity` becomes visible.
Replace the `onStart()` and `onStop()` method in `MainActivity` to make it look like this

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Start sign in if necessary
    if (shouldStartSignIn()) {
        startSignIn();
        return;
    }

    // Apply filters
    if(!mAdapter.ifStarted())
        onFilter(mViewModel.getFilters());
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}
```

Add this method to `FirestoreAdapter`

```
public boolean ifStarted() {
    return (mRegistration != null);
}
```

It´s always a good ide to detach listener so add this in `MainActivity`

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Hope it´s helps and add breakpoints wherever you feel uncertainty and step walk the code to see what´s happening.

Comment: Thank you, Erik, got the idea that nothing to do with firestore but still confused about how to save adapter position

Comment: Actually you dont have to save the position the list of restaurants will not move. But for this you must stop the adapter from reloading when you go back from `RestaurantDetailActivity`

Comment: This worked for https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/383